# Jackson cannot parse control character

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my API response, I have control-p character. Jackson parser fails to serialize the character and throws an error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted
>   character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 16)): has to be escaped using backslash to
>   be included in string value

I have investigated and found that Jackson library actually tries to catch for ctrl-char.

Can anyone suggest solutions or work around for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix similar problem by setting Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS ([documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html)) on JsonParser 
.

The code in my case looks:

```
parser.setFeatureMask(parser.getFeatureMask() | JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS.getMask());
```

As stated by others, such JSON is invalid, but in case you have no chance to change JSON, this should help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to configure the mapper to force escape non-ASCII?

This might be enough:

```
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
```

see [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#commonly-used-features)

But I agree with [StaxMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59501/staxman): the JSON response should be well formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, it does not escape control characters. I agree with both of you, but there is nothing I can do with the source.

Comment: You really should try filing a bug against whoever is producing malformed request/content, if at all possible. They may not be aware of the problem, and if so, can't fix. I realize that it may not solve your immediate problem, but without reporting such problems these problems will keep on getting worse for everyone.

Comment: Setting the mapper.configure() as described above RESOLVED my similar issue: Our user may enter Non-ASCII chars in our UI string input fields (comments, etc.). This mapper configuration forces escaping of non-ASCII characters (neutralize it) thus avoiding the JSONParseException. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Content you get is not valid JSON -- as per JSON specification, control characters MUST be escaped within String values, and CAN NOT exist outside of them. So I would recommened getting input data fixed; it is corrupt, and whoever is sending it is not doing good job of cleansing it, or properly escaping.

Barring that, you can write a `Reader` (or even `InputStream`) that filters out or converts said control characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realize that it is not a valid JSON, but org.json library actually parses it fine unlike Jackson library. So I was actually looking to find a more sophisticated solution. However, I think you right. It might be only way or I go write a custom Jackson library.

Comment: No, not custom Jackson library, just underlying Reader/InputStream that cleanses input. I am surprised that `org.json` does not check for this actually, since it tries to catch spec violations.