Jackson parsing issue
In my spring applicaiton, I have Rest api, when I call it using postman
and sending this json
{
    "incomeValue":"Test\\t"
}

It gives
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 9)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value

The application is deployed on tomcat.
and I can't remove \t

You have a comma at the end of your json which looks like it shouldn't be there.

Not related, I updated the quesiton

Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594503/jackson-cannot-parse-control-character -- apparently you can configure Jackson to accept control characters

Just created a barebones Spring Boot project with a RestController that has a Post endpoint and was able to send the exact json you used with no issue

@ZackMacomber have you deployed to tomcat? or using intelliji, because it is not duplicated with intellji

I created a 3.2.4 Maven Spring Boot app via Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io) and only included Spring Web as a dependency.
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <name>demo</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Spring Boot Application:
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Rest Controller:
@RestController
public class DemoRestController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello");
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> test(@RequestBody Test test) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(test);
    }
}

Test class:
public class Test {
    private String incomeValue;

    public String getIncomeValue() {
        return incomeValue;
    }

    public void setIncomeValue(String incomeValue) {
        this.incomeValue = incomeValue;
    }
}

Deployed to my local 10.1.20 tomcat server and then posted to the endpoint with your json with no issue:
http://localhost:8080/demo/test

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2024 12:46:26 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "incomeValue": "Test\\t"
}


have you deployed to tomcat? or using intelliji, because it is not duplicated with intellji –

Deployed to my local 10.1.20 tomcat server and worked fine there as well. I'll update my answer with more of my files.
